# ICA for noise reduction of covariance matrix

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, independent-component-analysis

Trying to understand ICA in the context of noise reduction of covariance matrices (of dimensionality M).

I understand in PCA, you can reconstruct the covariance matrix by squaring the first N principal component loadings (where N < M):

```
loadings = pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_)
low_rank_covariance = numpy.dot(loadings, loadings.T)
```

Then you can add back in a diagonal matrix `D` which contains the unexplained/missing variance.

I'm not super familiar with ICA, but is there an analog to this procedure for ICA? I understand that there no longer are the explained variance (eigenvalues) because ICA is maximizing the kurtosis rather than the variance. However you still get a basis with ICA. Can you infer the loadings somehow?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. ICA is also just a linear model just like PCA, so you will still get weights or loadings for each component. ICA transformation is not orthogonal tho.